# Preg_replace string with wildcard in middle

Tags: php, regex

i want to replace a specific tag in a svg-code-string. The tag looks like this:

```
<rect x="0" fill="#C1984F" width="120" height="80"/>
```

But the color should be replaced with a different color ...

I think it should work like this:

```
$thumbContents = preg_replace('<rect x="0" fill="*" width="120" height="80"/>', '<rect x="0" fill="'.$selectedColor.'" width="120" height="80"/>', $thumbContents);
```

But i dont know how to write the regex-pattern.

Comment: Consider using DOM instead of regex for this.

Comment: simply find the index of `fill="*"`  and replace (appned) with the new string without using regex.

Comment: I think DOM is quite to heavy for this purpose ... this is the only case i need to modify tags like this. And its always this tag.

Comment: To search for the index isnt possible because there are other tags with the fill-attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you insist to use regexes for this...

```
$tag = '<rect x="0" fill="#C1984F" width="120" height="80"/>';

$newc = 'red';

echo preg_replace('~(<rect[^<>]+?fill=")([^"]+)~', "$1$newc", $tag);
```

The pattern means

```
(<rect[^<>]+?fill=") - group 1: "<rect" then anything (but not <>) until fill="
([^"]+) - group 2: anything but not a quote (i.e. the color value)
```

Replacement:

```
$1 - whatever has been captured by the group 1
$newc - new color value
```

Comment: You should do `~(<rect[^<>]+?fill=")[^"]+~` instead. It avoids saving useless information and processing a new group, which speeds up a tiny little bit.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var list = document.getElementsByTagName("rect")[0];
    alert(list.getAttribute('fill'));// change the value here

});
</script>
<rect x="0" fill="#C1984F" width="120" height="80"/>
```

sorry but it is in javascript.

Comment: Thanks mate but i need a PHP variant because i generate a download with the changed file